# Implementing an Efficient ContentProvider on Android

Tags: android, database, sqlite, listview

I'm currently working on a SQLite code base with a table that can hold a large amount of records. It has so many records that using a `LoaderManager` to asynchronously retrieve `Cursor` objects is becoming slow to display them in a `ListView` with a `CursorAdapter`.

If there is one row change in the table being queried, the `LoaderManager` is notified, and a new `Cursor` is retrieved. But, this seems inefficient because the `Cursor` queries for all the rows in the table for the `ListView`. The GUI isn't being blocked because the `Cursor` loading is being done in another thread, the problem is that the retrieval of the table rows can take a while. 5-10 seconds can pass on some slower phones before the new record information is displayed.

I'm trying to find a way to efficiently retrieve row changes to update the `ListViews`'s rows without reloading everything.

I've looked into rewriting my code as a internal `ContentProvider` (hiding `SQLiteDatabase`) because I've seen it can be used with the app's `ContentResolver` to send out individual row change notifications via `notifyChange()`.

If I switch to a `ContentProvider`, will it be as efficient as I've assumed? Upon individual record changes, can the `ContentProvider` send out events that will allow a `ListView` to reload only the row change information, and not require a complete requery of all the table information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when implementing query() method of your ContentProvider return a custom. AbstractWindowedCursor, that way even if the final data set is huge you just fill the small window

Comment: Could I use an `AbstractWindowedCursor` without rewriting to use a `ContentProvider` as well, or does the `AbstractWindowedCursor` require a `ContentProvider` to exist?

Comment: no, you can use it as a stand alone Cursor, no ContentProvider required